# How to effectively multi-thread functions based on data received from a socket in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

Here is a snippet from a specific server program I a working on.

Requirements:

1. I want the program to initiate a socket on port defined by `ownport` variable and listen on that port for incoming TCP messages.
2. Based on the specific value I receive on the socket from remote hosts, the server has to initiate functions `func1()` or `func2()` [Example: if the value is `JOIN`, then execute `func1` and if it is `UPDATE` execute `func2`]
3. These actions are mutually exclusive and multiple clients may be connected to the server at the same time and might be sending requests.

How can I effectively multithread this so that the server constantly listen on the port and initiate the functions based on the incoming requests in realtime?

```
# Creating a socket 
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();
print "Socket created!"

#Binding the socket to specified ports
try:
    sock.bind((ownhost, ownport))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket bind complete'

# Listening for incoming requests
sock.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

# Handling the incoming requests received
req = conn.recv(1024)
reqpro = req.split('|')
# If the request is a join request
if reqpro[0] == "JOIN":
    func1(reqpro, arg2)
elif (reqpro[0] == 'UPDATE') and (reqpro[1] == 'PRED'):
    func2(reqpro,arg2)
else:
    print "invalid request type"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You will many options at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socketserver.html

Comment: Can't use `socketserver` library. I am stuck with the libraries included in default installation. Is there a way to use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to do this? preferably the former. @KlausD.

Comment: `socketserver` is part of the standard library.

Comment: Why am I getting name not defined error on import socketserver if it is a part of standard installation? Am I doing something wrong here.?